# GetFullYear() function does not come after setting date from calendar?

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I got a calendar which I want to take birthday of user. Its `id` is "DatePicker"

```
var tarih = new Date();
tarih =($("#DatePicker").val());
alert(tarih);
```

When I run this code I get the date from calendar. The problem occurs when I try to get year which is selected at calendar:

```
var tarih = new Date();
tarih =($("#DatePicker").val());
alert(tarih.getFullYear());
```

The code above didn't work. I checked date functions at SO but couldn't find this kind of example.

Comment: what does tarih return in the first instance?

Comment: the date i select from calender @MildFuzz

Comment: as a string, an object, an array?

Comment: maybe you need to go back to your JS books? Knowing how to establish type is fundamental.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can request a `Date` instance directly;

```
var tarih = $("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate");
alert(tarih.getFullYear());
```

Comment: It didnt work at first cause of ur "#datepicker". The id is "DatePicker" after that it worked. Thanks a lot @Alex K.

Answer (score 1):

i don't know much about JQuery but most probably .val() method will return you a string, so its actually not a date object you have to convert it into a date object before using getFullYear method, you can use Date.parse() function to convert a string to date object

Comment: var tarih = new Date();
       
        tarih =($("#DatePicker").val());
        Date.parse(tarih);
        alert(tarih.getFullYear()); 
    }

didnt work @Saket

edited..

Comment: can you give output of ($("#DatePicker").val()) ? is it a date or a string?

Comment: the output is like 03/09/2012

Comment: aah then it was my mistake you can do this   `var tarih = new Date(Date.parse(($("#DatePicker").val()))); alert(tarih.getFullYear());`